# Remove numpy rows which don't contain whole numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array

```
a = np.array([[1, 2.0, 3],
              [1.23,2.5,3],
              [1,4.6,4.9]])
```

I want to check each value in the 2nd column for a whole number and keep that row if it is a whole number. I have tried this.

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    try:
        if a[i,1].is_integer()==False:
            a=np.delete(a,(i),axis=0)
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

**Output:**

```
array([[1. , 2. , 3. ],
       [1. , 4.6, 4.9]])
```

**Desired output:** `array([[1. , 2. , 3. ]])`

**Reason for failure:** When a row is deleted, `i` the row below moves up. Getting the desired output without using `delete` is also okay.

Comment: `a[(a == np.floor(a)).all(1)]`?

Comment: @Yakym. Arguably more efficient to extract the column first, so you don't need to call `all` for the whole array.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you're right, I missed that bit.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko It fails when I change ```a[2,1]``` to 4. Please try with ```a = np.array([[1, 2.0, 3], [1.23,2.5,3], [1,4,4.9]])```

Comment: @BibekMishra You could try @Mehdi's solution instead. There are some numerical precision issues, for example if you have `0.999999999999999999999999` in one of the entries, both mod and floor will give wrong answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
output = a[np.mod(a[:, 1], 1) == 0]
```

Answer (score 4):

You may do so using `np.floor`, as follows:

```
output = a[a[:, 1] == np.floor(a[:, 1])]
```

Or, you can do it using `astype(int)`, as follows:

```
output = a[a[:, 1] == a[:, 1].astype(int)]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It fails when I change the ```a[2,1]``` to 4. Please try with 

a = ```np.array([[1, 2.0, 3],
                  [1.23,2.5,3],
                  [1,4,4.9]])```

Comment: The last row of the array in the comment is ```[1,4,4.9]``` whereas it's ```[1,4.6,4.9]``` in the question.

Comment: Output in this case should return 1st and 3rd row of the original array since the 2nd column in both these arrays are whole numbers.

Comment: I see. Just noticed that you want to compare only the 2nd column (not all columns). Check my updated answer, please.

Comment: Yes, works now. I guess, it's not very different from @Mehdi's answer.

Comment: Cool. Yeah, different ways to decide whether a number is an integer or not.

Comment: @BibekMishra Just added another alternative.